# Select the python version in a terminal

Tags: python, ipython, term

I want to open a python interpreter in a buffer with ipython. So I use that, from the term-mode :

```
(make-term "ipython" "/usr/bin/env" nil "ipython" (or filename "")
           "--TerminalIPythonApp.force_interact=True"))
```

But I don't know where to precise the python version that I want to use : my default version is python2.7 and I want to start an interpreter with python 3.4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was :

```
(make-term "ipython" "/usr/bin/env" nil "ipython3" (or filename "")
   "--TerminalIPythonApp.force_interact=True"))
```